# bcp syntax for dbname.schema.table

Tags: sql-server-2012, bcp

Trying to do something very simple here with **SQL Server 2012**... I'm trying to follow the steps found here:
http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1083/bulk-insert-with-text-qualifier-in-sql-server

I'm using the Windows Authentication method.

```
bcp dbname.schema.Products format -c -t -f d:\test.fmt -T
```

What exactly do I put as dbname.schema.Products?

My database is called [Manipulate MC BS], the table is called [MASTER]

do I write the following?:

```
bcp [Manipulate MC BS].dbo.[MASTER] format -c -t -f d:\test.fmt -T
```

Any help would be great!

Cheers,
Lucas

Answer (score 1):

Try using quotation marks or specifying the -q parameter as suggested before (or just do both, it won't hurt).

```
bcp "[Manipulate MC BS].dbo.[MASTER]" format -c -t -f d:\test.fmt -T
```

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Specifying Identifiers That Contain Spaces or Quotation Marks

SQL Server identifiers can include characters such as embedded spaces and quotation marks. Such identifiers must be treated as follows:

- When you specify an identifier or file name that includes a space or quotation mark at the command prompt, enclose the identifier in quotation marks ("").

For example, the following bcp out command creates a data file named Currency Types.dat:

```
 bcp AdventureWorks2012.Sales.Currency out "Currency Types.dat" -T -c
```

To specify a database name that contains a space or quotation mark, you must use the -q option.

- For owner, table, or view names that contain embedded spaces or quotation marks, you can either:
- Specify the -q option, or
- Enclose the owner, table, or view name in brackets ([]) inside the quotation marks.